# How to create a array/vec of Chisel modules

Tags: chisel

I created a CHISEL Class (extends) module called SaturatingCounter (code below in case it is relevant).

I want an array/Seq of these counters in another module.

EDIT: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621533/how-to-do-a-vector-of-modules). But when I try

```
 val vec_of_elements = Vec.fill(10) {Module(SaturatingCounter(4)).io}
```

I get an error

```
Error:(72, 29) value fill is not a member of object chisel3.Vec
  val vec_of_elements = Vec.fill(10) {Module(SaturatingCounter(4)).io}
```

**Rest of the original question**

So I tried creating a Vec as shown below. That does not work because my Class is not of type Data. I could make it inherit Data but since I am still a beginner that looks like a big leap.

```
var foo = Vec(10,SaturatingCounter(4))
```

**Error message:**

```
Error:(46, 23) inferred type arguments [something.SaturatingCounter] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T <: chisel3.Data]
  var foo = Vec(10,SaturatingCounter(4))

Error:(46, 47) type mismatch;
 found   : something.SaturatingCounter
 required: T
  var foo = Vec(10,SaturatingCounter(4))
```

Is the right solution to create a Array/Sequence of SaturatingCounter s?

**SaturatingCounter**:

```
class SaturatingCounter (bits: Int) extends Module {
  require(bits >= 2)
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val valOut: SInt = Output(SInt(bits.W))
    val inc: SInt = Input(SInt(bits.W))
  })

  val count = RegInit(SInt(bits.W), 0.S)

  val minVal: SInt = ((1 << (bits-1)).asUInt())(bits-1,0).asSInt()
  val maxVal: SInt = (((1 << bits) - 1) >> 1).asSInt(bits.W)

  var sum : SInt = count + io.inc

  var operandsSignSame : Bool = io.inc(bits-1) === count(bits-1)
  var sumSignDifferent: Bool = sum(bits-1) =/= count(bits-1)

  when(operandsSignSame && sumSignDifferent) {
    when(count(bits-1)) {
      count := minVal
    }.otherwise {
      count := maxVal
    }
  }.otherwise {
    count := sum
  }
  io.valOut := count
}

object SaturatingCounter {
  def apply(bits: Int): SaturatingCounter = new SaturatingCounter(bits)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this to get the create the modules and get access to their `io`.

```
  val vec_of_elements = Vec(10, Module(SaturatingCounter(4)).io)
```

That works form me.

Note the `.io`, by adding that you are getting some of type `Data` and you have access to all the `io`s of the modules you've created here.

In general you only need a Vec if you want to use hardware
based indexing of the elements, or your Elements are part of an IO. If you don't need that you can just use a Scala collection like Seq, Array or similar.